# How do I create an array of the previous 31 days using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

Using moment.js I'm trying to generate an array of the previous 31 days in a particular moment.js format. This is my current code:

```js
let labels = [];
const popArray = () => {
    let nowMonth: any = moment().format('D');
    let newMonth = parseInt(nowMonth);
    let startMonth = newMonth - 31;
    for(let i = startMonth; i < newMonth; i++){
        labels.push(moment().day(i).format('MM-DD'));
    }
    console.log(labels)
}
popArray();
```

When I run this code I get an array of 31 days, the first being "11-10" and the last being "12-10". Why is this? I've tried different configurations where `startMonth` is "-31" and `newMonth` is "0" but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply using the subtract method like this:

```
let labels = [];
    const popArray = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 31; i++){
            labels.push(moment().subtract(i, "days").format('MM-DD'))
        }
        console.log(labels)
    }
popArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the day to an integer and looping that way, use the built-in [`momentjs` function `subtract`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) to walk back the 31 days from the current date, then loop forward using the `add` function in `momentjs`.

```
const DAYS = () => {
  const days = []
  const dateStart = moment().subtract(31, 'days')
  const dateEnd = moment()
  while (dateEnd.diff(dateStart, 'days') >= 0) {
    days.push(dateStart.format('MM-DD'));
    dateStart.add(1, 'days')
  }
  return days;
}
console.log(DAYS())
```